# What is this kind of singing called?

Tags: technique, voice, terminology

I'm not quite sure how to describe it, the genre is swing if that helps. Please see the link below which starts at around 3 minutes in:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of singing is called *[scat singing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing)*.

Comment: Another example [at 2:36 in this video](https://youtu.be/VpwdFz3-dQc?t=2m36s) with [Michel Legrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Legrand) and [Nana Mouskouri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nana_Mouskouri).

Comment: Not to mention the popular 90's dance music song entitled [Scatman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hy8kmNEo1i8)...

Comment: Look up the meaning of scat...

Comment: Now the name Scatman makes more sense because I was wondering why he chose such an unsavoury name